# joomla spambots error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Using widgetkit map (external component by yootheme) in joomla 2.5, joomla detect when I insert an email address and give me this error

> This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.

Javascript obviously is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have the plugin `Content - Email Cloaking` active ?
Disable it and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a programmer or webdesigner, you should look for any JavaScript error messages with a tool of your choice, which will help you to identify the problem.

There are several possible causes. Here are two of them:

1. Sometimes, a content plugin interferres with the tags or output of
   another plugin. Obviously, the email cloak plugin is called and
   executed correctly (thus the message), but the JavaScript to display
   the email address seems to be corrupted. You could try to re-order
   the plugins, so that the email cloak plugin is executed after all
   3rd party (i.e., not default Joomla) plugins.
2. A JavaScript library is not loaded. This often happens in
   conjunction with templates. To check this, switch your installation
   to a standard template (e.g. Beez2). If the problem vanishes,
   correct your template.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in three ways.

- Email Cloaking plugin Disable.
- While using custom Module Prepare content Disable.
- Using Place holders to fix the issue on particular article.

For more about [Joomla spambots error](http://www.walkswithme.net/this-email-address-is-being-protected-from-spambots-in-joomla)

Hope its helps someone.